# Led bulb body getting hot touch in one socket but not other

Tags: light, bulb

The LED bulb body in one particular socket gets hot. I changed the bulb the socket and checked the wiring to the button for any loose wire. Still bulb in that particular socket gets hot while same bulb in other socket doesn't. Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

All LED bulbs get hot, but the bulbs and fittings are designed to dissipate the heat.

- Something is covering the fitting, not letting heat escape

  - Check in the ceiling space, perhaps insulation is on top of it
- The wiring is loose or broken so the bulb is getting intermittent power

  - You need a multimeter to check for this.
- Assuming its an Edison Screw, the tongue ta the bottom is not making contact properly.  This is dangerous, don't do it if you are not confident that you can do it safely.

  - Turn the lights on
  - Flip the breakers until it goes off
  - Remove the bulb
  - Pull the tongue up with a wooden implement or an insulate screwdriver.
  - Put everything back